# Excel if condition

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm doing an `if` condition in Excel:

```
=IF(M1071="Si";1;0)
```

I want to find the Si value in a cell and return the number 1, or else return O.

However the cells don't just have `Si`, the names have more characters such as `C8H20O2SSi2Si2`

Any idea how to search the cell that have `Si`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this: `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Si";M1071));0;1)`.

Comment: Just in case: `FIND' is case sensitive, use `SEARCH` for case insensitive lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a list of elements that you want to filter for rows that contain `Si`, you can alternatively just use the Autofilter directly. First apply the autofilter to the range you want to filter (in the *Data* tab->*Sort & Filter*->*Filter* - or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>)

In the column that you want to search for `Si`, click on the filter arrow in the top row and select *Text filters*->*Contains...* - and enter `Si` here.